# OpenCV Virtual Envornment

Tags: opencv, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I have successfully installed OpenCV on my Macbook running High Sierra using Homebrew, but I am having trouble getting it recognised in a virtual environment.

I have successfully created a virtual environment called cv. When I enter it by typing workon cv in terminal the command prompt correctly shows that I am in the virtual directory. When I run python it shows me that I have version 3.7 installed (as opposed to 2.7 when I am not in the virtual env. But when I try to import cv2 I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

When I look in:

```
cd ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

it contains cv2.so

Something is not pointing somewhere correctly but I don't know where to look to correct it.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Followed this link and managed to install everything correctly:
[OpenCV4 and Mac OS](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/#comment-490374)